# Округлить число в меньшую сторону до 2х знаков после запятой

Tags: java

Например, есть переменная:

```
float f = 0.1692f;
```

Нужно округлить, чтобы получилось `0.16`.

Comment: округлить число или вывод числа? Решения то разные будут...

Comment: Нужно изменить тип на BigDecimal и потом прочитать его методы и все будет хорошо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 float f=Math.floor(100*f)/100.0f
```

Answer (score 3):

*Тело сообщения должно ...*

```
((int)(100 * f)) / 100.0f
```

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.printf("%0.2f", Math.PI);
```